# How to search multiple things with .loc

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-loc

If there is a more effecient way please let me know.

```
pk.loc[pk['Type 1'] == 'Grass']
```

I want to do this but also search with `Type 2` being `Ground`, but I can't find the syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
pk.loc[(pk['Type 1'] == 'Grass') | (pk['Type 2'] == 'Ground')]
```

exclusively both:

```
pk.loc[(pk['Type 1'] == 'Grass') & (pk['Type 2'] == 'Ground')]
```

Comment: That gave me grass types and ground types, I was trying to get it ones that are exclusively both

Comment: Edited to respond to your comment.

Comment: Note the need for the parenthesis in this answer. The order of operations are `|, &` before `==`. Forgetting those parenthesis is a common mistake.

Answer (score 0):

In your case do

```
out = pk.loc[pk['Type 1'].eq('Grass') & pk['Type 2'].eq('Ground')]
```